# Use Java Lambda to collect values from Reflection

Tags: java

I have a data bean that comes from a large table with pattern-based column names. I need to use Lambdas to find the count of `Goal*`'s that are `TRUE`. The Getters can be invoked via reflection.

```
public class PersonBean {
   //...

   // + with Getters/Setters
   private Boolean goalResearch;
   private Boolean goalAcademia;
   private Boolean goalGovt;
   private Boolean goalProfit;
   //...
}
```

On a single field I can do reflection as

```
Boolean valueAcademia = (Boolean)(p.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getGoalAcademia").invoke(p));
```

Wondering how to quickly collect that with Streams/Lamdas.
(Result: `Goals: 6`, 6 `goal*` Boolean fields were `TRUE`)

Comment: From list of  `PersonBean`  ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Can you give more details? Also you have `getDeclaredMethods()` to get all methods(even setters).

Comment: @Eklavya Not a List; **each PersonBean** has these multiple columns. So for each PersonBean, I need to get a Count of "Goal*" Booleans that are TRUE.

Comment: So you want to get dynamic all value attributes which start with `goal` and are boolean?

Comment: @KunLun and that are TRUE. So if 6/20 goal* Booleans were TRUE, the count is 6. I need to stream my methods, filter by name, invoke, and count the TRUE's, in other words. The fields are dynamic, I can't hard-code them.

Comment: You have a list of methods you want to invoke? I ask this because you can use reflection to get direct attribute, without invoke getters

Comment: I just need the bean values. If there's a way to get the values without methods (the attributes are private) that can work as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something in the lines of this should give you the result you need:

```
Arrays.stream(PersonBean.class.getDeclaredMethods())
      .filter(declaredMethod -> declaredMethod.getName().startsWith("isGoal"))
      .filter(declaredMethod -> {
          try {
            return (Boolean) declaredMethod.invoke(personBean);
          } catch(final IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException exception) {
            return false;
          }
     })
     .count()
```

Comment: Normally a boolean attribute has method with `isAttribute`.

Comment: Yes fair point @KunLun, especially with libraries such as Lombok. However, I was just following's the OP's example.

Comment: Works well, only change is I made is `catch (Exception e`) (general case and no finals), because it was still complaining about something improperly getting thrown. So just `try { .. } catch (Exception e) { .. }`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below to get the count of all `true` values of the goal* fields of the `PersonBean` type object.

```
Arrays.stream(person.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) //gets all methods
      .filter(method -> method.getName().startsWith("getGoal") 
               && method.getReturnType().equals(Boolean.class)) //gets all getters for goal* Boolean fields
      .filter(getter -> {
             try {
                return (Boolean) getter.invoke(person); //invokes the getter
             } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                return false;
             }
      })
      .count();
```

You can also combine the 2 filters into a single one as below

```
Arrays.stream(person.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) //gets all methods
      .filter(method -> {
             if(method.getName().startsWith("getGoal") 
                && method.getReturnType().equals(Boolean.class)) {
                try {
                   return (Boolean) method.invoke(person); //invokes the getter
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                   return false;
                }
             }
             return false;
      }) //gets all true values for goal* fields
      .count();
```

Comment: What does `.filter(result -> result)` do?

Comment: If you don't add `.filter(result -> result)`, you'll get all the boolean values. But since you are interested in only true values, you need to use that filter @geneb.

Comment: I see. Matthew Formosa's version is `filter & filter`, and you did `filter & map & filter(result->result).` In his reply, the 2nd Filter can automatically filter the TRUE's.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have made a solution for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    PersonBean personBean = new PersonBean(true, true, false, false);

    int goalCounter = countGoals(personBean);

    System.out.println(goalCounter);

}

public static Integer countGoals(PersonBean personBean){

    if(personBean == null){
        return 0;
    }

    //get all fields from parameter
    Stream<Field> stream = Arrays.stream(PersonBean.class.getDeclaredFields());

    return stream.filter(e -> {

                    if(e.getName().startsWith("goal")){

                        //because its private, should call this
                        e.setAccessible(true);

                        try{
                            return (boolean)e.get(personBean);
                        }catch(Exception e1){
                            return false;
                        }

                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }

                }).mapToInt(e -> 1).sum();

}
```

Also you can improve filter with more conditions. I picked just the fields which name starts with `goal`

Comment: What does `mapToInt(e->1).sum()` do, is that equivalent to `.count()`?

Comment: `mapToInt` it's like `map`, but after execution you have just `integers`. And `sum()` sum all integers. So the result will be an `Integer`. `count()` it's `mapToLong.sum`, which returns a `Long`, which in your case it's just a waste to use `Long`. I'm convinced you don't have more fields than value of `Integer.MAX VALUE`.

Comment: Thanks, tested, it's working. Good solution, a bit long, but it works.

Comment: @geneb. You can split it in 2 filters. One which check `goal` and the other value.